# Look up table in R referencing row values and specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, lookup-tables

I have a multipart lookup table problem in R.
I have a data frame, where the number in each column represents an item name. The item name can be found in the corresponding look up table.

Data:

```
  > food.dat
      Fruit Vegetable Meat Dairy
    1     1         2    2     3
    2     3         2    1     1
    3     3         2    2     2
    4     2         2    1     1
    5     1         1    1     2
```

Lookup Table:

```
> food.lookup
    FoodItem Number  FoodName
1      Fruit      1    Banana
2      Fruit      2     Apple
3      Fruit      3     Mango
4  Vegetable      1    Carrot
5  Vegetable      2  Broccoli 
6       Meat      1   Chicken
7       Meat      2      Fish
8      Dairy      1    Cheese
9      Dairy      2    Yogurt
10    Dairy       3  IceCream
```

Note that the number is not unique amongst foods. For example, a 1 represents a different FoodName in column Fruit (Banana) and a different FoodName in column Vegetable (Carrot).

I would like to recode the food.dat dataframe to have the FoodName value from the lookup table.
If possible I would also like to be able to use a simple function and supply a FoodName and return a dataframe from food.dat which includes only rows that include that specified FoodName.

Thank you for your time and thoughts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` the named `vector` by the 'FoodItem' into a `list` from the 'food.lookup'.  Loop `across` the 'food.dat' columns, extract the `list` element and replace the values by matching

```
library(dplyr)
lst1 <- with(food.lookup, split(setNames(FoodName, Number), FoodItem))
food.dat %>% 
    mutate(across(all_of(names(lst1)), ~ lst1[[cur_column()]][as.character(.)]))
```

-output

```
 Fruit Vegetable    Meat    Dairy
1 Banana  Broccoli    Fish IceCream
2  Mango  Broccoli Chicken   Cheese
3  Mango  Broccoli    Fish   Yogurt
4  Apple  Broccoli Chicken   Cheese
5 Banana    Carrot Chicken   Yogurt
```

#### data

```
food.dat <- structure(list(Fruit = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Vegetable = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), Meat = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Dairy = c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))
food.lookup <- structure(list(FoodItem = c("Fruit", "Fruit", 
"Fruit", "Vegetable", 
"Vegetable", "Meat", "Meat", "Dairy", "Dairy", "Dairy"), Number = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), FoodName = c("Banana", "Apple", 
"Mango", "Carrot", "Broccoli", "Chicken", "Fish", "Cheese", "Yogurt", 
"IceCream")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I was wondering if you could clarify for me what this piece of code is doing : ~ lst1[[cur_column()]][as.character(.)] ?

Comment: @ksweet the `cur_column()` returns the column name of the looped column in `across`.  `split` returns a `named` `list`.  So, by using `lst1[[cur_column()]]`, it exdtract the list element for that column name, then we use th match with the named vector of the list and the value of the column.  The `as.character` is to make sure that it won't match by index i.e. even if the column values are 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. it should work rather than just 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0):

On a similar note, you can make use of the "position" of your different names.
For this split the looup table into the respective food-types (or type them out by hand). Then simply use the indexing to set the results.

Below it is done for one example. You can readily expand this to all.
I store the results in Dairy2 so you can compare and see how the indexing works.

```
dairy <- c("Cheese","Yogurt","IceCream")
food.dat <- data.frame(Dairy = c(3,1,2,1,2))

food.dat$Dairy2 = dairy[food.dat$Dairy]

food.dat
  Dairy   Dairy2
1     3 IceCream
2     1   Cheese
3     2   Yogurt
4     1   Cheese
5     2   Yogurt
```

Answer (score 0):

We can pivot the data to a long format, with one food item by row, join to the lookup table, and pivot back to wide format

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

food.dat %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowid, names_to = "FoodItem", 
               values_to = "Number") %>% 
  left_join(food.lookup) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid, names_from = FoodItem, 
              values_from = FoodName)


#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   rowid Fruit  Vegetable Meat    Dairy   
#>   <int> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   
#> 1     1 Banana Broccoli  Fish    IceCream
#> 2     2 Mango  Broccoli  Chicken Cheese  
#> 3     3 Mango  Broccoli  Fish    Yogurt  
#> 4     4 Apple  Broccoli  Chicken Cheese  
#> 5     5 Banana Carrot    Chicken Yogurt
```

---

With data:

```
food.dat <- read.table(text =
'Fruit Vegetable Meat Dairy
1         2    2     3
3         2    1     1
3         2    2     2
2         2    1     1
1         1    1     2', header = TRUE)

food.lookup <- read.table(text =
'FoodItem Number  FoodName
    Fruit      1    Banana
    Fruit      2     Apple
    Fruit      3     Mango
Vegetable      1    Carrot
Vegetable      2  Broccoli 
     Meat      1   Chicken
     Meat      2      Fish
    Dairy      1    Cheese
    Dairy      2    Yogurt
    Dairy       3  IceCream', header = TRUE)
```